A short fantasy fiction in the London Tube
The main character in this novelette (or maybe a short novella) is really the Tube, which is what Londoners call their subway. It is a story totally different from the novel I asked about in A fantasy novel under London.
But the POV character is human, an American. With his wife, for the past 20 years or more, he attends every year an international conference, which meets in a different place each year. I don't remember what type of conference it is. From my personal experience, it might well be a scientific one. Often more an occasion to meet old friends and make new acquaintances than attend all the talks.
Twenty years ago, it was held in London. At that time the couple was not so affluent. They stayed in a rather shabby hotel and used the Tube a lot, as they could not afford to take regularly a cab (i.e., a London taxi). This year, first time it is in London again,  their social status is higher. They stay in a posh hotel and the wife has made a point to always take a cab and never the Tube, which she says she had loathed last time they were there. But the husband told her he'll take it whenever he has to go someplace, not to spare money, this is now moot, but because it is faster than a cab in London traffic, and in fact really because he likes the Tube.
On the first day, after the lectures, he has an errand to do and takes the Tube. But when his train enters the station, he feels a strong blast of air with a stink of powder. He thinks there had been an explosion, possibly a terrorist attack. But nobody seems to pay any attention to this blast. I'm not sure whether on this day he experiences this again. But on the second day, he had more errands to do and spends hours in the Tube (and misses some of the talks). And, not in all stations, but in several ones he again experiences a blast of foul air, but a different stink depending on the station (sewer, carrion, ...). And again, nobody seems to pay attention.
He spends the entire third day exploring the Tube, (to Hell with the talks !) to determine in which stations these blasts occur. He finds a correlation with the stations which were hit during the Blitz. Also he remarks that while most of the passengers of the Tube do not show any sign they have felt these blasts, a few ones, mostly elderly, do show by their behaviour that they felt something similar as what he felt.
That evening he goes to the theatre with his wife and some friends. At some point he tells his wife why he was absent all day and the theory he had devised to rationalise these blasts: the blasts of the German bombs of the Blitz never dissipated and still survive (after all these decades) and move from station to station. His wife says she does not believe such nonsense.
But all the theaters on that street end at the same time and all cabs are taken by all those reaching the street together, and grudgingly the wife agrees to take the Tube. When the train arrives he feels the blast, remarks one or two old persons who act as if they did, too. But his wife is almost sick, white and trembling. As the husband asks she answers that of course she had felt it. Already 20 years before, contrary to him, she already did, and that was the reason she loathed the Tube. She is much more sensitive than he is. And she knows that, indeed, it is a memory from the Blitz, but not a physical one (that would not have survived decades) but an "emotional" one, only felt by some sensitive people like her. (This is the element of Fantasy of the story.)
Finally they arrive at the station for their hotel. It is very deep and there is a long escalator going out. They see something bizarre. There is some confusion at the top of the elevator as an old woman has stopped moving and blocks the exit. She acts as the few people who do feel a blast. But since the husband and his wife have not felt it yet, it means it comes from the outside, not from below.
And indeed when it does reach them just seconds later instead of a stink of death and despair it is fresh air from the outside (fresh air from a London street ????? This is totally "fantastic") full of hope and love and life.

Wow. A short story to describe the novella. Well remembered!

The Winds of Marble Arch by Connie Willis. It won the 2000 Hugo Award for Best Novella and was nominated for the World Fantasy Award for Best Novella.
It starts with the protagonist Tom and his wife Cath arguing about using the tube:

Cath refused to take the Tube.
“You loved it the last time we were here,” I said, rummaging through my suitcase for a tie.
“Correction. You loved it,” she said, brushing her short hair. “I thought it was dirty and smelly and dangerous.”
“You’re thinking of the New York subway. This is the London Underground.” The tie wasn’t there. I unzipped the side pocket and jammed my hand down it. “You rode the Tube the last time we were here.

And ends as you describe with the old lady blocking the exit:

The old lady was still standing poised at the top of the escalator, her head back, her eyes closed. People jammed up behind her, saying irritatedly, “Sorry!” and “May I get past, please!” She didn’t hear them. Head tilted back, she sniffed deeply at the air.
“Oh,” Cath said, and tilted her head back, too.
I breathed it in deeply. A scent of lilacs and rain and expectation. Of years of tourists reading England on $40 a Day and newlyweds holding hands on the platform. Of Elliott and Sara and Cath and me, tumbling laughingly after the Old Man, off the train and through the beckoning passages to the District Line and the Tower of London. The scent of spring and the All Clear and things to come.


Yes, without any doubt !

Heh.  I knew that was familiar but I was still digging through books in the basement to find it.
